# Chain reorganisation: How often one confirmation transactions do not end up to the first block the wallet thinks

Tags: web3js, metamask, chain-reorganization

Currently web3.js wallets like MetaMask work so that they return the transaction receipt to the dApp as soon as the Ethereum node, connected internally by the wallet itself, sees one confirmation for the transaction.

However, there might be chain reorganisations in the Ethereum blockchain. This block was not the heaviest tip of the chain and the transaction later ends up in some other block, not one the wallet originally thought.

How often this happens? How often transactions are reorganised in another block? Where could I track such stats?

Asking this because sometimes this is a usability issue in dApps. Assuming the wallet tells the transaction went through, you query the blockchain and you find out that the state change did not actually happen yet because the blockchain was reorganised.

I know the solution is to wait more block confirmations, but that is not what I am asking here.

Comment: did you check this yet? links to etherscan also. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/distribution-of-chain-reorganization-events